# Can i generate a .exe with a WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is possible to generate a .exe from another .exe? using visual studio and net framework ? for example the application grab a .dll and convert into a standalone .exe app

Comment: The answer is yes, there are several ways to do this, however these *"can i write a program with a program"* type question tend to be *XY* questions

Comment: thanks, but i cant find what function should i use? or where to start??

Comment: If linked dulicates are not enough search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+generate+exe+runtime and [edit] question to clarify why existing approaches did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [How to combine DLLs with .exe inside of a wpf / winforms application (with pictures)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891550/how-to-combine-dlls-with-exe-inside-of-a-wpf-winforms-application-with-pictu)

It explains what you are looking for. Works for both wpf and winforms.